# What's the best way to be notified when an extension's toolbaritem is being used?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, mutation-events

I want to setup `label` attributes, and event listeners for a `toolbaritem` when it's being used. Because even though I add my extension's `toolbaritem` to `<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">` it is not found by `document.getElementById` unless it is being used. At the moment I have `DOMNodeInserted` event listeners on the navigation bar and add-on bar which sets up my `toolbaritem`'s attributes, but I'm wondering if there is a better way?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Have a look at [**Broadcasters and Observers**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Broadcasters_and_Observers). I think this will help you.

Comment: I just read it, it doesn't appear to be helpful. It appears to describe how you can broadcast changes to multiple elements in a document, but I want to know when a toolbaritem is added to browser.xul, which seems to me to be a completely different problem.

Comment: @Erik Vold: What event listeners do you want to add to the button? You said *which sets up my toolbaritem's attributes*. You could have the attributes and event handlers set on the broadcaster instead and let the toolbarbutton observe them.

Comment: Thanks Felix, this is a better way to solve my problem for now, but doesn't answer my question.

Comment: If you edit your response I'll change my vote (I can't otherwise..)

Comment: @Erik Vold: I think the problem is to find the right timing ;)

Answer (score -1):

Are you calling `document.getElementById` too early, possibly before Firefox has added the item into the toolbar? If so, you might want to move your code to a function which is registered to be called on the `"load"` event on the main browser window. This should ensure that the browser, including the toolbar, has been successfully built by the time your code runs.

Comment: The document.getElementById call is in a "load" event listener, the item dne and this appears to be because the user needs to customize the toolbar and add it.